# Laravel clean url issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, virtualhost

I know this is a issue alot of people have but even after fixing everything I still don't get any result.

At this moment when I go to

> shorty.../public/users

I get the following

> shorty../public/index.php/users was not found on this server.

But when I add index.php in the url bar then it works. ( the not clean version )

this is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my httpd.conf file

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `RewriteRule` to `^ index.php`. Also, and if that fails, please share your entire virtual host config for the domain you're working with so that I can see your document root.

If your Laravel installation is not at the root of your domain, then you will need to add a `RewriteBase`. For example, if you installed it in a folder inside a public document root, like `//localhost/myfolder/`, then your `RewriteBase` must be set to `/myfolder/public/`.

Also, if you installed Laravel above your webroot, and not below (which is **not recommended**), then your `RewriteBase` should be set to `/public/`.

But, like I said, I can't tell where everything is, relatively speaking, to your host domain. So if the above doesn't work, then please update your question with the full virtual host config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same preoblem, It worked for me by shifting to Xampp server and putting `'index' => '',` inside the `app/config/app.php`. Hopefully it will work for u too. Happy Coding.